# How to select multiple files with Plyer Filechooser

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How to select multiple files with Plyer FileChooser? I am able to select a single file though.
I tried this:

```
filechooser.open_file(multiselect=True)
```

but it doesn't work. Also, the [docs](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.FileChooser) doesn't have much info.

Also, where can I find more about the argument (like how to specify the filetype) that I can pass to the `open_file` and other methods, because the docs doesn't have much info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://cloudstack.ninja/guhan-sensam/plyer-filechooser-on-android-select-multiple-files-not-working/).

You can pass `multiple=True`.

The docs are admittedly not very clear, but [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/c17fd019cc49ae62a3a1d7aaec2ba6ad39035b74/plyer/platforms/android/filechooser.py#L148) is the relevant portion of the source code for this functionality.

Comment: @Mayank If this answer helps you, please mark it as accepted answer